# Reverse sort a listing in my code in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, reverse

I have a listing which I need to be reverse sorted, current it is sorted ascending.

Obviously I can’t put the whole code here. But what happens in this code is it gets the listing from the server and it is in below format. My data structure is this:

```
$listing->id 
$listing->address 
$listing->city 
$listing->price 
$listing->status 
$listing->dateModified 
$listing->fullThumbnailPath 
$listing->virtualTourUrl 
$listing->closedDate 
$listing->listingDate 
$listing->isListingAgent
```

The below code sorts the listing using the function `sortListings`. This sorting method sorts the data in ascending order or listing status, the listing status are sold, leased, listed and escrow, currently this list is showing first sold, escrow leased, listed. I want this listing to be reverse sorted so that the listed is shown first then escrow, leased then sold.

I know its only a condition needs to be changed but I tried all combinations but it doesn’t seem to be working.

```
usort($listingArray, 'sortListings');

function sortListings($a, $b) {

    if ($a->compareStatusClass($b) != 0) {
        return $a->compareStatusClass($b);
    } else {
        if ($a->getClosedDate() != null) {
            if ($a->getClosedDate() == $b->getClosedDate()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return $a->getClosedDate() > $b->getClosedDate() ? -1 : 1;
            }
        } else {
            if ($a->getListingDate() == $b->getListingDate()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return $a->getListingDate() > $b->getListingDate() ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function compareStatusClass is used by the above function:

```
public function compareStatusClass($listing) {
    if ($this->getStatusClass() == $listing->getStatusClass() ||
        ($this->getStatusClass() == 'sold' && $listing->getStatusClass() == 'leased') ||
        ($this->getStatusClass() == 'leased' && $listing->getStatusClass() == 'sold')) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if ($this->getStatusClass() == 'listed') {
            return -1;
        }

        return ($this->getStatusClass() == 'escrow' && ($listing->getStatusClass() == 'sold' || $listing->getStatusClass() == 'leased')) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

The final data is served as HTML (showing two fields for example)

This is the code

```
$listing->getPrice()
$listing->getClosedDate()
```

This is the result

```
$3,980,000
Sold Date: 07/14/2013
```

Comment: you just need to negate your comparison function

Comment: @JakeGould `function sortListingsR($a,$b){return -sortListings($a,$b);}` Unless I am remembering something wrong. Whether that is a good way to do it is another question.

Comment: @JakeGould as far as I know, `rsort` accepts a flag, not a function. And there is no `ursort`

Comment: @TimSeguine where should I put negate sign in above functions, please let me know?

Comment: It's giving me message "Call to undefined function sortListings()"

Comment: @JakeGould sorry for that, have edited the main post to add the code at the end.

Comment: @user3677174 I used the same name for the function as you did in your code listing. If it is undefined, then that is not my fault. I am not in the mood for hand-holding today.

Comment: @TimSeguine Thanks for the help really appreciate it. I don't need hand holding, was telling you the error I got, the function is defined in the code.

Comment: @user3677174 Sorry, knee jerk reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing this line:

```
usort($listingArray, 'sortListings');
```

To these two lines which adds [`rsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) to the mix:

```
usort($listingArray, 'sortListings');
rsort($listingArray);
```

Also—as suggested by `niconoe`—[`array_reverse`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) might work as well:

```
usort($listingArray, 'sortListings');
$listingArray = array_reverse($listingArray);
```

Comment: This is good, or if you don't want to (or can't) change your function, use array_reverse() on the output

Comment: Thanks JakeGould, I tried it, it does not work. Can you please suggest some other solution in the function code above?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the usort rsort combo will work. It will be the same as doing a rsort, or not?

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for your answer, it didn't fit in my scenario, but this is right, there was some problem in my code elsewhere hence it was not applying.